# Vagrant - share host VPN with guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, vagrant

So I have an interface for a VPN connection (`jnc0`), and also a vagrant guest which talks to my machine through another separate interface (`vboxnet1`). My host OS is OS X Mountain Lion, and the Vagrant (VM) guest OS is CentOS 6.3.

How can I set something up so that the CentOS guest will be able to talk to hosts on the other side of the VPN through my OS X host?

Comment: Do you need external clients to connect to your VM?

Comment: Also, can you configure your guest to establish its own separate VPN connection independent of your host?

Comment: I want to be able to connect to the servers on the other side of the VPN from my VM (so NAT is fine), and no I can't, since the VPN features three-factor authentication, and I can only do it from my host OS.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Virtualbox as your VM provider, I've successfully used this snippet to enable the use of a host VPN connection on a guest VM.

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
end
```

You may have seen the following code snippet online which no longer works on newer versions of Vagrant:

```
Replaces the earlier config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
```

Comment: Saved my day, mate!