# Vagrant - share guest VPN with host

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vagrant

There already is a topic about sharing the host vpn with the guest ([Vagrant - share host VPN with guest](https://superuser.com/questions/542709/vagrant-share-host-vpn-with-guest)). Is there a way for the other way around?